# Rails app - passing updated instance variable values to prawn after AJAX form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I have a static page in my Rails application where a user can select two dates in a form and then an income statement will generate based on those two inputs. This works fine. However, on that same page I also have the option to generate a PDF (I am using the prawn gem). In the controller I send my instance variables to prawn. Now when I generate the PDF it will display the date values as:

```
@date1 = Date.today - 1.month
@date2 = Date.today
```

even if the user has updated the form with new dates. The value of the instance variables passed to prawn are from when the server first generated the page (even if the value of those instance variables has changed with a subsequent form submit). Is it possible to pass to prawn the updated values (after a user submits the form)? If so, how do I go about doing this?

```
def income
  if (params.has_key?(:date1) && params.has_key?(:date2))
      year1 = params[:date1][0...4].to_d
      month1 = params[:date1][5...7].to_d
      day1 = params[:date1][8...10].to_d
      year2 = params[:date2][0...4].to_d
      month2 = params[:date2][5...7].to_d
      day2 = params[:date2][8...10].to_d
     @date1 = Date.new(year1,month1,day1)
     @date2 = Date.new(year2,month2,day2)
  else  
     @date1 = Date.today - 1.month
     @date2 = Date.today
  end 

  respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.pdf do
        pdf = IncomePdf.new(@date1, @date2)
        send_data pdf.render, filename: "Income Statement #{@date1} to #{@date2}",
                          type: "application/pdf",
                          disposition: "inline"
     end
  end

end
```

Here is what the form in the view looks like:

```
<%= form_tag "/income", :method => :post, :remote => true, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do %>
```

Comment: Should work, are you sure your if condition is evaluating to true?

Comment: Yes, because in the view the data changes to the correct dates if I submit the form, but if I load the PDF, it always shows the value of `@date1 = Date.today - 1.month @date2 = Date.today`